# Use text link as button in jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've downloaded an ajax/jquery conatct form with a normal button. But I want to replace the button with a text link. I have been trying a bunch of suggestions from the web, but none of them seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var post_url = form.attr('action');
        var post_data = form.serialize();
        $('#loader', form).html('<img src="loader.gif" /> Please Wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: post_url, 
            data: post_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                    form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <div>
         <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="loader">
    <a href="#" class="submit">Submit</a> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var post_url = form.attr('action');
        var post_data = form.serialize();
        $('#loader', form).html('<img src="loader.gif" /> Please Wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: post_url, 
            data: post_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                    form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    }).delegate('a.submit', 'click', function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace the submit button with a `<a />` tag :

In your HTML, replace the `<input />` tag :

```
<div id="loader">
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> -->
    <a id="yourID" href="" >Your Text</a>
</div>
```

Attach an event handler to the new `<a />` tag with jQuery :

```
$("#yourID").on("click",function(){
    $("#contact_form").trigger("submit");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Button with

```
<a href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
```

Then use the following code (after or before your Form ajax code)

```
$('#submit').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#contact_form').submit();
});
```